# How to override sha bang interpreter in shell scripts recursively?

Tags: bash, interpreter, shebang

I've a master shell script which calls functions defined in various other shell scripts. The master script includes other scripts using 'source' command.
I want to use a common interpreter for all the scripts regardless of what the she bang ("#!/bin/sh") has been set to in those scripts. I want to supply that interpreter from command line. 
for example:

master.sh (with #!/bin/sh)

subscript1.sh (with #!/bin/sh)

subscript2.sh (with #!/bin/sh)

subscript3.sh (with #!/bin/sh)

master.sh calls functions which are defined in the subscripts and are included as 'source subscript1.sh', 'source subscript2.sh' and 'source subscript3.sh'.

When I run ./master.sh, the subscript use their respective interpreters as directed by "#!/bin/sh" line. I want to run all of them using '/bin/bash', the master and the subscripts but without changing the she bang line because there are a lot of such scripts. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Call the interpreter explicitly:

```
bash ./master.sh
```

Note that the shebang line has no effect on scripts run using `source`. That command always executes the script in the current shell process, so it uses whatever interpreter is currently running.

But this all seems dangerous. If someone writes `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`, it may have dependencies on `sh` syntax that would be violated if `bash` were used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Barmar. However, I've tried doing that and it doesn't work. I believe the idea of having a she bang line was to use the defined interpreter regardless of which process or shell starts the script. I certainly need some clarity on this.

Comment: That's not how shebang works. It tells the kernel how to execute the script if you run it as a command by itself, instead of as an input file to an interpreter.

Comment: `bash ./master.sh` is just like `cat ./master.sh`. They both run the specified command, and give the filename as an argument. `bash` interprets the file, `cat` prints it.